# Update view of a NavigationController simulating a push

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uinavigationcontroller, xib

Can i make a push of a view with the animation and only update it´s contents?
I have 4 views that are the same, so instead of creating 4 xibs, i wanted to update the view but give the user the impression that he had switched views.

So i don´t really want to make a push, i only want to give that impression to the user.
Is this possible?

Comment: So what you have tried. Are you able to switch the view without animation?

Comment: Still haven´t tried switching the view without the animation. That shouldn´t be a problem. I only have to call my controller .text and give new content. But without the animation it´s not very perceptive to the user, that he changed the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a simple project with one VC and button in the middle to trigger the animation. Here is the code tied to the button:

```
- (IBAction)pushNewView:(id)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    // this moves the view off screen to the left
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // this pops the view over to the right side of the screen
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        // and this slides it in from the right
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    }];
}]; }
```

You can play around with the timing to make it look a little more "native", and play with the alpha as previously mentioned. You can alter this in either of the two animation blocks.

Comment: Just as a little extra note, make sure you change the background color of self.window to be the same as the background color of the view your animating, otherwise you get a brief second where the screen is black (default background color of the window). Setting the alpha to 0.3 and then back to 1.0 also works nicely.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach to this (imho) is to pop the current view without animation and then immediately push the same view again.

```
myNavigationController = self.navigationController;
[myNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[myNavigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

This is part of the technique I use to give the effect of an unlimited number of views whilst in reality only using/keeping one in memory.

When wanting to handle the "back" navigation you would push a new one without animation and then pop it with animation.

```
myNavigationController = self.navigationController;
[myNavigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
[myNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you share how you accessed myNavigationController and myNavController?

Comment: ah, myNavController and myNavigationController would be the same thing (copy and paste error above which I'll fix now).

Answer (score 0):

you can animate one view to the left and at the same time animate the next view from the right, this will be the same as a push (assuming next and current views are already subviews)

```
UIView *nextView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    currentView.frame = CGRectOffset(currentView.frame, -self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0f);
    nextView.frame = CGRectOffset(nextView.frame, -self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0f);
}];
```

it would probably look better if you experimented with changing the alpha property of the views as well

Comment: currentView will be equal to self.view and nextView will be one that i have created with UIViewController?

Comment: in that example they would both be subviews of self.view. if you are creating a view with a view controller, and then doing a fake push, its seems pointless, you should just push a new instance of the view controller